# Problems with static tf publisher

Tags: ros, simulation, rviz, urdf, state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using my own URDF file for my custom built robot, the robot is properly visible and moves properly in rviz, If I run the simulation with /odom publisher.

But when open the camera nodlet with openni_launch and publish a static tf, then the laser scanner in the simulation starts to rotate randomly, I don't have idea why this is happening.

I publish the static tf in launch file which contains:

```
<launch>
        <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser" args="0.1 0 0.455 0 0 0 base_link camera_link 100"/>
</launch>
```

Below are my rqt_graph

[image: image description]

Please find the below frames.pdf

[image: image description]

and the slam_gmapping node gives the following warnings

```
[ INFO] [1409662993.035030893]: Laser is mounted upwards.
 -maxUrange 9.99 -maxUrange 9.99 -sigma     0.05 -kernelSize 1 -lstep 0.05 -lobsGain 3 -astep 0.05
 -srr 0.1 -srt 0.2 -str 0.1 -stt 0.2
 -linearUpdate 1 -angularUpdate 0.5 -resampleThreshold 0.5
 -xmin -100 -xmax 100 -ymin -100 -ymax 100 -delta 0.05 -particles 30
[ INFO] [1409662993.055169092]: Initialization complete
update frame 0
update ld=0 ad=0
Laser Pose= 0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
m_count 0
Registering First Scan
update frame 6
update ld=0.0282843 ad=1.5708
Laser Pose= 0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
m_count 1
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-0.0229554
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4160.76
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4167.38
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Average Scan Matching Score=0.964133
neff= 24.6526
Registering Scans:Done
update frame 8
update ld=0.0282843 ad=1.5708
Laser Pose= 0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
m_count 2
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4035.6
lp:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
op:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
Average Scan Matching Score=110.041
neff= 2.2353
*************RESAMPLE***************
Deleting Nodes: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 Done
Deleting old particles...Done
Copying Particles and  Registering  scans... Done
update frame 9
update ld=0.0282843 ad=1.5708
Laser Pose= 0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
m_count 3
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4009.6
lp:0.257682 -1.50465 1.55431e-15
op:0.237682 -1.48465 -1.5708
Average Scan Matching Score=165.453
neff= 3.99713
```

Any idea why this is happening.?

Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191701/problems-with-static-tf-publisher/) by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Just a quick idea:

Your static publisher is trying to publish a transform between `base_link` and `camera_link` while in your frames.pdf, they are already connected via `base_link => scan_support => camera_link` which is published by `robot_state_publisher`. I can't see your static publisher in the tree (I think it would show up as "Broadcaster")

My guess: Your static publisher and the robot-publisher are publishing different transforms for the same "connection", which is why Rviz is switching constantly between the values from both publishers.

Hope that helps,

Rabe

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-09-04**:
Perfect, the robot_state_publisher and static_publisher both are publishing the transform between base_link and camera_link.
I have conformed this even by running the roswtf.

Solved the problem.

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-09-04**:
Many thanks